# jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this jQuery menu script:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.blowfish = function() {

    // hide original ul dom tree
    $(this).hide();

    // create container from top-level li tags
    var top = $(this).children('li');
    var container = $('<div/>').addClass('bfcontainer').attr('id', 'cv' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10e10)).insertAfter(this);
    var topdiv = $('<div class="top"></div>').appendTo(container);

    // check if IE and set fixed width for first column
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $('.top').width('200px');
    }

    $.each(top, function(i, item) {
        var topitem = $(':eq(0)', item).clone().data('sub', $(item).children('ul')).appendTo(topdiv);

        if($(topitem).data('sub').length) {
            $(topitem).addClass('hasChildMenu');

            if($.browser.safari) {
                $(topitem).css({'margin-right' : '15px'});
            }
        }
    });

    // event handlers
    $('a', container).live('click', function() {
        var container = $(this).parents('.bfcontainer');

        // click handler
        var level = $('div', container).index($(this).parents('div'));

        // remove blocks to the right in the tree, and 'deactivate' other links within the same level
        $('div:gt('+level+')', container).remove();
        $('div:eq('+level+') a', container).removeClass('active').removeClass('inpath');
        $('.active', container).addClass('inpath');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if($(this).data('sub').children('li').length) {
            // add submenu if container has children
            submenu(container, this);
        }
        else {
            // show title or link if container has no children
            var title = $('<a/>').attr({href : $(this).attr('href')}).text($(this).attr('title') ? $(this).attr('title') : $(this).text());
            var featurebox = $('<div/>').html(title).addClass('feature').appendTo(container);

            // set width
            var remainingspace = 0;

            $.each($(container).children('div').slice(0, -1), function(i, item) {
                remainingspace += $(item).width();
            });

            var fillwidth = $(container).width() - remainingspace;

            $(featurebox).css({'top': 0, 'left' : remainingspace}).width(fillwidth).show('slow');
        }

        return false;
    });
};

// create submenus
function submenu(container, item) {
    var leftPos = 0;

    $.each($(container).children('div'), function(i, mydiv) {
        leftPos += $(mydiv).width();
    });

    var submenu = $('<div/>').css({'top' : 0, 'left' : leftPos}).appendTo(container).fadeIn();

    // check if IE and set fixed width for submenu column
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $(submenu).width('200px');
    }

    var subitems = $(item).data('sub').children('li');

    $.each(subitems, function(i, subitem) {
        var subsubitem = $(':eq(0)', subitem).clone().data('sub', $(subitem).children('ul')).appendTo(submenu);

        if($(subsubitem).data('sub').length) {
            $(subsubitem).addClass('hasChildMenu');

            if($.browser.safari) {
                $(subsubitem).css({'margin-right' : '15px' });
            }
        }
    });
}  
})(jQuery);
```

The original DOM tree is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item</a>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery scripts adds a new column for every sub menu (like the Mac OS X finder) and I want to modify it so if there are no more sub menus it actually gets the href attribute of the link and behaves like a normal  (I am using AJAX to load content into another div if you click on an item without subitems so I can't use window.location in the script itself but rather have to disable the return false in that specific case. How do I do this?

You can view a working example here: http://mxms.me/blowfish

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, going to answer my own question :D!

Here is the update JS:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.blowfish = function() {

    // hide original ul dom tree
    $(this).hide();

    // create container from top-level li tags
    var top = $(this).children('li');
    var container = $('<div/>').addClass('bfcontainer').attr('id', 'cv' + Math.floor(Math.random()*10e10)).insertAfter(this);
    var topdiv = $('<div class="top"></div>').appendTo(container);

    // check if IE and set fixed width for first column
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $('.top').width('200px');
    }

    $.each(top, function(i, item) {
        var topitem = $(':eq(0)', item).clone().data('sub', $(item).children('ul')).appendTo(topdiv);

        if($(topitem).data('sub').length) {
            $(topitem).addClass('hasChildMenu');

            if($.browser.safari) {
                $(topitem).css({'margin-right' : '15px'});
            }
        }
    });

    // event handlers
    $('a', container).live('click', function() {
        var container = $(this).parents('.bfcontainer');

        // click handler
        var level = $('div', container).index($(this).parents('div'));

        // remove blocks to the right in the tree, and 'deactivate' other links within the same level
        $('div:gt('+level+')', container).remove();
        $('div:eq('+level+') a', container).removeClass('active').removeClass('inpath');
        $('.active', container).addClass('inpath');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if($(this).data('sub').children('li').length) {
            // add submenu if container has children
            submenu(container, this);

            return false;
        }
        else {
            // show title or link if container has no children
            /*
var title = $('<a/>').attr({href : $(this).attr('href')}).text($(this).attr('title') ? $(this).attr('title') : $(this).text());
            var featurebox = $('<div/>').html(title).addClass('feature').appendTo(container);

            // set width
            var remainingspace = 0;

            $.each($(container).children('div').slice(0, -1), function(i, item) {
                remainingspace += $(item).width();
            });

            var fillwidth = $(container).width() - remainingspace;

            $(featurebox).css({'top': 0, 'left' : remainingspace}).width(fillwidth).show('slow');
*/
            /* window.location($(this).attr('href')); */
        }
    });
};

// create submenus
function submenu(container, item) {
    var leftPos = 0;

    $.each($(container).children('div'), function(i, mydiv) {
        leftPos += $(mydiv).width();
    });

    var submenu = $('<div/>').css({'top' : 0, 'left' : leftPos}).appendTo(container).fadeIn();

    // check if IE and set fixed width for submenu column
    if($.browser.msie) {
        $(submenu).width('200px');
    }

    var subitems = $(item).data('sub').children('li');

    $.each(subitems, function(i, subitem) {
        var subsubitem = $(':eq(0)', subitem).clone().data('sub', $(subitem).children('ul')).appendTo(submenu);

        if($(subsubitem).data('sub').length) {
            $(subsubitem).addClass('hasChildMenu');

            if($.browser.safari) {
                $(subsubitem).css({'margin-right' : '15px' });
            }
        }
    });
}  
})(jQuery);
```

Cheers,
Max